# cloze package: Clozes in math mode have stopped working

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, underline, cloze

I recently updated my MacTeX distribution via Tex Live Utility.

Before that clozes from the `cloze` package have also worked in math mode, e.g. in `amsmath`'s `align` environment.

But that does not seem to be the case anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cloze}
        \clozesetfont{}

\begin{document}
In text mode, \cloze{one can have clozes}, but not in math mode:
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2=\cloze{c^2}.
\end{align}
In inline math, on the other hand, it does work:   $a^2+b^2=\cloze{c^2}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the `cloze` package does not seem to have been updated, I wonder whether something happened with `amsmath` or the like. – Has anybody else made this observation?

**EDIT:** 
@egreg's comment puzzled me a bit because I knew I had already used `cloze` inside `align`. After digging a bit deeper, it is possible that my **M**WE was a bit too minimal. Apparently one can have a `cloze` inside `align` if everything is inside a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, siunitx}
\usepackage{cloze}
    \clozesetfont{}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
In text mode, \cloze{one can have clozes}, but not in math mode:
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2=\cloze{c^2}.
\end{align}
In inline math, on the other hand, it does work:   $a^2+b^2=\cloze{c^2}$.

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2=\cloze{c^2}.
\end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I guess I withdraw my initial question as I cannot say for sure that a change has occurred. I only stumbled across the issue when I was debugging another thing...

On the other hand, it is a bit funny that the `tcolorbox` environment changes a feature of the `align` inside.

Comment: What exactly is it suppose to do in math mode? I tested with lualatex from TL19 and TL18 and TL17 and I seem to get the same result?

Comment: It is not `amsmath`, commenting out the package and swapping to a standard math display environment has the same problem.  It could be a change in lualatex.

Comment: @daleif Clozes used to work in math mode pretty much as they do in text mode, i.e. underline the contents and color/hide it. Please see the updated MWE above.

Comment: I get exactly the same with TL from 2015 to 2019. No underlining inside `align` in every setup. It has *never* worked in `align`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for clarifying. Interestingly, I must have been using `cloze` inside `align` inside `tcolorbox` all the time, see my edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m the maintainer of the cloze package. Update to the newest version of cloze. Typesetting cloze texts in inline and display math mode should now work.

I believe the cloze package never worked in display math mode until version 1.5.

https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.1416.1590664252.3866.ctan-ann@ctan.org

Comment: Thanks for the update! Unfortunately, I cannot confirm that it works. After updating the TL packages, cloze does not work anymore at all. While loading the package, an error message "cannot find the file file cloze.tex" is issued. Only after restoring an older version of cloze can I compile my projects again.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I believe that is a packaging problem. I recently added a plain TeX version named cloze.tex. TeX live installed this file in ./texmf-dist/doc/luatex/cloze/cloze.tex. It should be in ./texmf-dist/tex/luatex/cloze/cloze.tex. Maybe you can put the cloze.tex in the right position https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Josef-Friedrich/cloze/master/cloze.tex . I already wrote to CTAN.

Comment: I wrote to TeX Live. The cloze package should work again. Give it a try.

Comment: Excellent. In today's version, everything is in its right place. Thank you for your work on this nice package!